# How do you call a script from another script in roblox studio

Tags: roblox

I was following a tutorial of AlvinBlox and came across not an error but it does not run something I wanted to happen.

Basically when the egg is clicked it need to hatch in a studio but it just prints the pet name and does not hatch the egg

This is the script where I need to code to call the script with the hatching mechanism:

```
local cost = 500
local petModule = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("PetModule"))

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    if player.leaderstats.Cash.Value >= cost then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - cost

        local pet = petModule.chooseRandomPet()
        print(pet.Name.." selected")
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player)
    end
end)
```

I was trying to hatch an egg but it doesn't hatch it.

Comment: Where is the code that handles the `HatchEgg.OnClientEvent` signal?

Comment: If it is neccessary i can add it into the code. Reply back

Answer (score 1):

You never passed the pet to the client.

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player, pet)
```

Comment: That didnt work because i didnt need to pass the pet to the client yet all i had to do was connect this script with another script which has the code to complete hatching the egg